# Windows 10 - Recreating Change to Start Menu to allow Recent Files in Tiles

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

Awhile back I was messing around with some of the setting in Windows 10 (mostly registry hacks) to customize everything, and I did something to make the Context Menu on my Taskbar and Start Menu awesome.

The only problem is that now I can't remember exactly what I did and I want to do the same change on my laptop.

In my start menu, the context menu on tiles shows recent files (just like it does when you right click a link in the taskbar:
[image: start menu context menu]

In the taskbar, the right click has a dark theme:
[image: taskbar context menu]

I did these changes with just a few changes to the registry - has anyone else seen this / know how I can recreate it?

Comment: What changes did you make specifically to your registry?  If you can't tell us what you did, we can't explain the behavior, and I realize thats part of your question.  You have to understand there are hundreds entries in the registry.  You have to narrow it down for us.

Comment: Yea I know but I can't remember what it was :( - I was hoping that somebody else has done a similar hack - it was only one or two entries that I changed so I was hoping that someone else might recognize it right away -

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out - these changes are part of the Windows 10 Update 1511 that is being pushed out to everyone - it seems they have built this cool functionality right in!